# Question regarding kernels and dimensions.

Tags: linear-algebra

My professor gave us a question and I would like some help in it.
The problem goes as follows:
Let $T:P_3 \to \mathbb{R}$ such that:
$T(a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3)=a_0+a_1+a_2+a_3$

Find the rank and nullity of $T$.

Here is what I know.

I know that if we find the kernel of $T$, we can find the dimension of the nullity of T. 
So I found that the nullity of $T$ was $3$. To find the rank we have to do $Rank(T)+Nulity(T)=n$. My professor said that the dimension was $4$ and therefore the $Rank(T)=1$. I'm confused as to how the dimension of $P_3$ is $4$. Can anyone explain?

Comment: The dimension of the space of polynomials up to a third order is 4. For it to be a subspace, it has to contain zero polynomial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well notice that you're describing its elements by four independent parameters: $a_0, a_1, a_2$ and $a_3$. Moreover, a basis for $P_3$ would be $\{1,x,x^2,x^3\}$, which has four linearly independent elements. Hence $P_3$ has dimension 4.

Alternatively to find the rank, notice that the image of $T$ clearly includes all of $\mathbb{R}$ (just consider all of the constant polynomials), which has dimension 1. Clearly this image can't be any larger than $\mathbb{R}$. Hence the rank is 1.